# How can i set different wallpapers for Ubuntu 15.04 login and Desktop

Tags: lightdm, 15.04

This has been bothering me very much. i have memory that Ubuntu 12.04 had this configuration? am i wrong? finally, is it possible for the login screen to have different wallpaper from the desktop? is this possible in Ubuntu 15.04? i would appreciate a stable understandable response. thanks :)  -ben

Comment: Ubuntu Tweak tool is good for that but as I can see it's not maintained for 15.04 yet. When the new distro comes out it has its own new features and boosts but it takes time for different useful apps/tweaks that you have used before to be available in your current new  distro.

Comment: Yes this  is exactly why im asking because every time i set "same as wallpaper" in ubuntu tweak lightdm damages. the password box has no input field, the icons on the login panell become odd, and when i type my password and hit enter, the password box looks like it was smudged all over the screen until the desktop appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and post what worked for me. I found multiple threads trying to tell me how to change this, but this method is the only one that worked for me on Ubuntu 15.04. Some of the steps might not be entirely necessary, these are just the steps I ended up taking.

1. Get the picture you want to put as the login screen background. Place it in `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and make sure the owner is `Root:Root` and the permissions match the other pictures in the folder (`-rw-r--r-- or 644`).
2. Navigate to `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` and open the file `com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml` in gedit.
3. Find the key name `background` and change the default to the path of your picture in "`/usr/share/backgrounds/`. For the key names `draw-user-backgrounds` and `draw-grid`, change the default value to `false`.
4. Save your changes, then run the command

   `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`
5. Restart the computer and your new login background should be there. Well, it was for me at least.

Hope this helps someone. No need to install anything, open `dconf-editor`, deal with the LightDM user or anything terribly complicated.

Source: [Changing the Wallpaper](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM)

Answer (score 0):

Open this file

```
/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
```

change background line with your wallpaper path

```
backgroud=/home/vahid/mybackgrouond.jpg
```

Also you can use Simple LightDM Manager.

[image: Simple LightDM Manager]

To install :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:claudiocn/slm
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simple-lightdm-manager
```

Comment: did you test this manager on 15.04? it's development seems to be left long time ago.

Comment: Not yet but you can try :)

Answer (score 0):

I have looked all around for an answer, too, and it seems that 15.04 breaks from convention in lightdm configurations.

I'm new to this, so it's not an elegant solution but it answer's your primary question. I renamed the background that I wanted to display at the lightdm login to the default background (warty-final-ubuntu.png) while adding .bak to the original background file.

```
cd /usr/share/backgrounds/
sudo mv warty-final-ubuntu.png warty-final-ubuntu.png.bak
sudo cp /path/to/my/background.png warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

Take it for what it's worth, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set different wallpapers for login screen and desktop, I found the working solution from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM#Show_Manual_Login_Box), which says:

> LightDM does not configure the look of greeters; to do this configure
>   the appropriate greeter.
>
> Unity Greeter by default shows the currently selected users
>   background. To set the default background and stop the switching edit
>   `/usr/share/glib- 2.0/schemas/10_unity_greeter_background.gschema.override`
>
> ```
>  [com.canonical.unity-greeter]
>  draw-user-backgrounds=false
>  background='/foo/wallpaper.png'
> ```
>
> And run `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` to
>   apply these settings.
>
> For LightDM GTK+ greeter edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`:
>
> ```
> background=/usr/share/lubuntu/wallpapers/lubuntu-default-wallpaper.png
> ```

Then just logout or restart to see the change, hope this helps :)