# How To have different login screen wallpaper on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: login, desktop-background

I would like to know if there is any way to change the login screen wallpaper, without changing the desktop wallpaper. In other words, how to independently change the login screen wallpaper. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/628665/how-can-i-set-different-wallpapers-for-ubuntu-15-04-login-and-desktop/668638 ?

Comment: it worked thnks

Comment: Also see this: http://askubuntu.com/a/694370/295286  A while ago I've put together a script based on the answer daisy linked. That'll make changing background far easier